# Alfresco lock out after installation of DigistaSigningAlfresco

Tags: apache, solr, windows-8, tomcat7, alfresco-share

After installing the amps, it works and was able to sign. But after restarting the tomcat server or the system (which automatically restarts the server), I could not log in again either as admin or other users on the share. Login returns the error: "Your authentication details have not been recognized or Alfresco may not be available at this time"

navigating to http://127.0.0.1:8080/alfresco shows the following error: 
HTTP Status 404 - /alfresco
type Status report
message /alfresco
description The requested resource is not available.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.52

Tomcat works fine at http://127.0.0.1:8080.

Am using windows 8 and Alfresco Share 4.2.f

> Catalina log:

1. May 21, 2015 3:04:00 AM
   org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init INFO: Loaded APR
   based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.1.29 using APR version 1.4.8.
   May 21, 2015 3:04:00 AM
   org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init INFO: APR
   capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false],
   random [true]. May 21, 2015 3:04:01 AM
   org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener initializeSSL INFO:
   OpenSSL successfully initialized (OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013) May
   21, 2015 3:04:01 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init INFO:
   Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"] May 21, 2015 3:04:01
   AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init INFO: Initializing
   ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"] May 21, 2015 3:04:01 AM
   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init INFO: Initializing
   ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8443"] May 21, 2015 3:04:01 AM
   org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load INFO: Initialization
   processed in 1252 ms May 21, 2015 3:04:01 AM
   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal INFO:
   Starting service Catalina May 21, 2015 3:04:01 AM
   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal INFO: Starting
   Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.52 May 21, 2015 3:04:01 AM
   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor INFO:
   Deploying configuration descriptor
   D:\Alfresco\tomcat\conf\Catalina\localhost\solr.xml May 21, 2015
   3:04:01 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule
   begin WARNING: [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property
   'debug' to '0' did not find a matching property. May 21, 2015
   3:04:07 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR INFO:
   Deploying web application archive
   D:\Alfresco\tomcat\webapps\alfresco.war May 21, 2015 3:04:56 AM
   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal SEVERE: Error
   listenerStart May 21, 2015 3:04:56 AM
   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal SEVERE:
   Context [/alfresco] startup failed due to previous errors May 21,
   2015 3:04:56 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
   INFO: Deploying web application archive
   D:\Alfresco\tomcat\webapps\share.war May 21, 2015 3:05:09 AM
   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory INFO:
   Deploying web application directory
   D:\Alfresco\tomcat\webapps\host-manager May 21, 2015 3:05:09 AM
   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory INFO:
   Deploying web application directory
   D:\Alfresco\tomcat\webapps\manager May 21, 2015 3:05:09 AM
   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory INFO:
   Deploying web application directory D:\Alfresco\tomcat\webapps\ROOT
   May 21, 2015 3:05:09 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
   INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"] May 21, 2015
   3:05:09 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start INFO: Starting
   ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"] May 21, 2015 3:05:09 AM
   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start INFO: Starting
   ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8443"] May 21, 2015 3:05:09 AM
   org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start INFO: Server startup in
   68159 ms May 21, 2015 3:50:32 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol
   pause INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"] May 21, 2015
   3:50:32 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause INFO: Pausing
   ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"] May 21, 2015 3:50:32 AM
   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause INFO: Pausing
   ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8443"] May 21, 2015 3:50:32 AM
   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal INFO: Stopping
   service Catalina May 21, 2015 3:51:00 AM
   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop INFO: Stopping
   ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"] May 21, 2015 3:51:00 AM
   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop INFO: Stopping
   ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"] May 21, 2015 3:51:01 AM
   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop INFO: Stopping
   ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8443"] May 21, 2015 3:53:33 AM
   org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init INFO: Loaded APR
   based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.1.29 using APR version 1.4.8.
   May 21, 2015 3:53:33 AM
   org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init INFO: APR
   capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false],
   random [true]. May 21, 2015 3:53:34 AM
   org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener initializeSSL INFO:
   OpenSSL successfully initialized (OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013) May
   21, 2015 3:53:34 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init INFO:
   Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"] May 21, 2015 3:53:34
   AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init INFO: Initializing
   ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"] May 21, 2015 3:53:34 AM
   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init INFO: Initializing
   ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8443"] May 21, 2015 3:53:34 AM
   org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load INFO: Initialization
   processed in 973 ms May 21, 2015 3:53:34 AM
   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal INFO:
   Starting service Catalina May 21, 2015 3:53:34 AM
   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal INFO: Starting
   Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.52 May 21, 2015 3:53:34 AM
   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor INFO:
   Deploying configuration descriptor
   D:\Alfresco\tomcat\conf\Catalina\localhost\solr.xml May 21, 2015
   3:53:34 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule
   begin WARNING: [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property
   'debug' to '0' did not find a matching property. May 21, 2015
   3:53:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR INFO:
   Deploying web application archive
   D:\Alfresco\tomcat\webapps\alfresco.war May 21, 2015 3:54:15 AM
   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal SEVERE: Error
   listenerStart May 21, 2015 3:54:15 AM
   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal SEVERE:
   Context [/alfresco] startup failed due to previous errors May 21,
   2015 3:54:15 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
   INFO: Deploying web application archive
   D:\Alfresco\tomcat\webapps\share.war May 21, 2015 3:54:23 AM
   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory INFO:
   Deploying web application directory
   D:\Alfresco\tomcat\webapps\host-manager May 21, 2015 3:54:23 AM
   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory INFO:
   Deploying web application directory
   D:\Alfresco\tomcat\webapps\manager May 21, 2015 3:54:23 AM
   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory INFO:
   Deploying web application directory D:\Alfresco\tomcat\webapps\ROOT
   May 21, 2015 3:54:23 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
   INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"] May 21, 2015
   3:54:23 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start INFO: Starting
   ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"] May 21, 2015 3:54:23 AM
   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start INFO: Starting
   ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8443"] May 21, 2015 3:54:23 AM
   org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start INFO: Server startup in
   49030 ms May 21, 2015 5:04:09 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol
   pause INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"] May 21, 2015
   5:04:09 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause INFO: Pausing
   ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"] May 21, 2015 5:04:09 AM
   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause INFO: Pausing
   ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8443"] May 21, 2015 5:04:09 AM
   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal INFO: Stopping
   service Catalina May 21, 2015 5:04:11 AM
   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop INFO: Stopping
   ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"] May 21, 2015 5:04:11 AM
   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop INFO: Stopping
   ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"] May 21, 2015 5:04:11 AM
   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop INFO: Stopping
   ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8443"] May 21, 2015 5:08:29 AM
   org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init INFO: Loaded APR
   based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.1.29 using APR version 1.4.8.
   May 21, 2015 5:08:29 AM
   org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init INFO: APR
   capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false],
   random [true]. May 21, 2015 5:08:30 AM
   org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener initializeSSL INFO:
   OpenSSL successfully initialized (OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013) May
   21, 2015 5:08:30 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init INFO:
   Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"] May 21, 2015 5:08:30
   AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init INFO: Initializing
   ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"] May 21, 2015 5:08:30 AM
   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init INFO: Initializing
   ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8443"] May 21, 2015 5:08:30 AM
   org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load INFO: Initialization
   processed in 988 ms May 21, 2015 5:08:30 AM
   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal INFO:
   Starting service Catalina May 21, 2015 5:08:30 AM
   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal INFO: Starting
   Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.52 May 21, 2015 5:08:30 AM
   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor INFO:
   Deploying configuration descriptor
   D:\Alfresco\tomcat\conf\Catalina\localhost\solr.xml May 21, 2015
   5:08:30 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule
   begin WARNING: [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property
   'debug' to '0' did not find a matching property. May 21, 2015
   5:08:33 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR INFO:
   Deploying web application archive
   D:\Alfresco\tomcat\webapps\alfresco.war May 21, 2015 5:09:07 AM
   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal SEVERE: Error
   listenerStart May 21, 2015 5:09:07 AM
   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal SEVERE:
   Context [/alfresco] startup failed due to previous errors May 21,
   2015 5:09:07 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
   INFO: Deploying web application archive
   D:\Alfresco\tomcat\webapps\share.war May 21, 2015 5:09:14 AM
   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory INFO:
   Deploying web application directory
   D:\Alfresco\tomcat\webapps\host-manager May 21, 2015 5:09:14 AM
   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory INFO:
   Deploying web application directory
   D:\Alfresco\tomcat\webapps\manager May 21, 2015 5:09:14 AM
   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory INFO:
   Deploying web application directory D:\Alfresco\tomcat\webapps\ROOT
   May 21, 2015 5:09:15 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
   INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"] May 21, 2015
   5:09:15 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start INFO: Starting
   ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"] May 21, 2015 5:09:15 AM
   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start INFO: Starting
   ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8443"] May 21, 2015 5:09:15 AM
   org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start INFO: Server startup in
   44451 ms

> Blockquote
>   
>   Please any help or information will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post `alfresco.log` file to see exact problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your **webapps** directory of tomcat should be like below image.

[image]

After installation of amp, the folder of alfresco and share are removed from webapps(under tomcat).Installation of amp is adding content in alfresco.war.The old war will be renamed as .bak file.I think after restarting alfresco your war files are not properly deployed.Check the size of alfresco(This should be around 160 mb) and share(This should be around 50-60 mb) folder.